# Add optgrop in existing dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, optgroup

How can I set opt group to below dropdown based on type:

my select box

[image]

I want to rearrange based on type , so all dropdown, checkbox, slider, quantity box will be display in group .
Also I want `<optgroup>` after each data-type

like `<optgroup >Dropdown</optgroup ><optgroup >slider </optgroup >`

I have tried via group by function but not getting correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version using forEach

```js
const sel = document.querySelector('.first-conditional-step');
const opts = [...sel.options].slice(1)
sel.options.length = 1; // keep the please select
const optGroups = new Set(opts.map(({dataset}) => dataset.type))
sel.innerHTML += [...optGroups].map(optGroup => `<optgroup label="${optGroup}">
  ${opts.filter(opt => opt.dataset.type===optGroup).map(opt=> opt.outerHTML)}
</optgroup>`).join("")
```

```html
<select class="first-conditional-step col-3" style="height: 35px;">
  <option style="font-size: 10px" value="0">Select an element</option>
  <option value="410090" data-type="Dropdown Menu">Title</option>
  <option value="750978" data-type="checkbox">option#11</option>
  <option value="751330" data-type="checkbox">option#22</option>
  <option value="751331" data-type="checkbox">option#33</option>
  <option value="751269" data-type="checkbox">b1</option>
  <option value="751270" data-type="checkbox">b2</option>
  <option value="751271" data-type="checkbox">b3</option>
  <option value="751273" data-type="checkbox">Name</option>
  <option value="751274" data-type="checkbox">Name</option>
  <option value="751275" data-type="checkbox">Name</option>
  <option value="751293" data-type="checkbox">Image1</option>
  <option value="751294" data-type="checkbox">Image2</option>
  <option value="751295" data-type="checkbox">Image3</option>
  <option value="751271" data-type="quantity box">QTY tooltip</option>
  <option value="751273" data-type="slider">Slider Tooltip</option>
  <option value="751328" data-type="checkbox">Name</option>
  <option value="751329" data-type="checkbox">Name</option>
  <option value="751274" data-type="slider"></option>
  <option value="751275" data-type="quantity box"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks , it works well, however I need all elements in single otgroup, like all checkbox under one optgrp, all slider in one slider otpgrp. like group. right now it appears multiple elements as optgrp for example slider, i need only one optgrp for all ements thanks in advance

Comment: there is duplicate element optgroup , like slider https://prnt.sc/0ma08Wvyp-ZD 
It should not be multiple , element optgrop should be single So only only one slider, checkbox, dropdown ....

Comment: in your generated dropdown , slider optgroup is two times it should be only one time , every optgroup should be one time only. hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Try now. Note the last two options have no text

Comment: Awesome, Thanks its working as expected!!!!!!!